# polymorphic association with formtastic and mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, polymorphic-associations, formtastic

I'm trying to create a relationship between two models in rails.

I have a Product and an Offer where an Offer belongs to a Product.

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

    has_many :offers, as: :trigger_product, :class_name => "Offer"

end

class Offer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

    belongs_to :trigger_product, polymorphic: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :product
end
```

in formtastic, the field for the trigger product is added as so

```
 <%= f.input :trigger_product, :as=> :select, :multiple => false, :collection => @offer.trigger_products_list %>
```

when I submit the form, I get an error

```
NameError in Admin::OffersController#create

uninitialized constant TriggerProduct

app/controllers/admin/Offers_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

It appears to me the polymorphic association isn't working, I don't think I should need to create an empty model to hold the TriggerProduct, but the error leads me to believe this is the issue.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this had to do with a the relationship needing to know of a product_type value, as product is a parent of many product types.

No way anybody here at SO would have gotten that and the Rails error didn't point in the right direction.

If somebody knows how I might have debugged that maybe a way to output all the required fields a relationship is expecting, I'll give you the points.

Comment: You haven't really included the relevant part for the error code (app/controllers/admin/offers_controller.rb) so we couldn't really help out. As far as debugging is concerned, I'd start there.